# Add Helm chart dependency repository as git url

Tags: github, kubernetes, charts, kubernetes-helm

I create a Helm chart that depends on several sub charts. I add the sub charts in the file `Chart.yaml`, this works well for charts from the stable repository.

But I also want to add dependencies on other charts. Currently I use `Helm install https://github.com/.../releases/my-chart.tgz` to install charts, which does not work in the `Chart.yaml` file at the moment. Is there a way to use this in the dependency field in the `Chart.yaml` file?

Is there also a way to use a git repository `https://github.com/my-chart/` as a reference to install a chart as a dependency?

Or is it really only possible to use chart repositories or locale chart directorys?

Thanks

Comment: Update for others going down this rabbit hole: There is no workaround at the moment. The latest discussion is https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/9461

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Github Pages](https://pages.github.com/) as your chart repository as in [this example repo](https://github.com/technosophos/tscharts)

More info in [helm docs](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/chart_repository#github-pages-example).

Comment: Yes, thanks. But there is no way to reference the charts in the same way as with 'Helm install ...`, right?

Comment: @bennex not unless you `wget` it first